# C++17 Variadic Template Folding

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates, fold, fold-expression

I don't understand why this doesn't work. Could someone who understands templates and variadic expression folding explain what is going on and give a solution that does work?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <typename... Args>
void print(Args... args)
{
    std::string sep = " ";
    std::string end = "\n";
    (std::cout << ... << sep << args) << end;
}

int main()
{
    print(1, 2, 3);
}
```

It should print out each of the args with a space in between and a newline at the end. It works if you remove the `sep <<` but then there is no space between each argument when it is printed.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The grammar for binary [fold-expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) must be one of:

```
(pack op ... op init)
(init op ... op pack)
```

What you have is `(std::cout << ... << sep << args)`, which doesn't fit either form. You need something like `(cout << ... << pack)`, which is why removing `sep` works.

Instead, you can either fold over a comma:

```
((std::cout << sep << args), ...);
```

or use recursion:

```
template <class A, class... Args>
void print(A arg, Args... args) {
    std::cout << arg;
    if constexpr (sizeof...(Args) > 0) {
        std::cout << sep;
        print(args...);
    }
}
```

Comment: For `(std::cout << sep << args, ...);` it says "expression not permitted as operand of fold expression". However it suggests I put parentheses around part of it like `((std::cout << sep << args), ...);` but that skips printing the first argument. Is there a version of this line that will work?

Comment: @nickeb96 Yep, forgot the parentheses. I'm not sure what you mean about the rest, it doesn't skip the first argument.

Comment: Ah, I got the second part working. It prints a leading `sep` however. Is there a straight forward way to have `sep` only in between each argument? Or does that require a more complex solution like recursion?

Comment: @nickeb96 If you want `sep` printed *after* each argument (no leading `sep`) then just move `sep` after `args`:  `((std::cout << args << sep), ...);` [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/NCu14w0YkfyId5GR)

Comment: @nickeb96 I know the question is two years old, but I just discovered fold-expression. And operator ?: with extra variable helps here: 
        `unsigned i = 0; 
        (  
           ( 
              std::cout << args 
                        << (    (++i<sizeof...(args))? ", " : " "     )   )  , ...      );`

Answer (score 15):

This will work, but it will print a trailing space:

```
template <typename... Args>
void print(Args... args)
{
    std::string sep = " ";
    std::string end = "\n";

    ((std::cout << args << sep), ...) << end;
}
```

[**live wandbox example**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Spno8pAERbM3uWZe)

---

In this case, a fold over the *comma operator* is being performed, resulting in an expansion like:

```
// (pseudocode)
(std::cout << args<0> << sep), 
(std::cout << args<1> << sep),
(std::cout << args<2> << sep), 
...,
(std::cout << args<N> << sep),
```

Comment: Does `args<0>` actually do something or was that just an example in pseudocode?

Answer (score 11):

What you really want to do is:

```
std::string sep = " ";
std::string end = "\n";
(std::cout << ... << (sep << args)) << end;
```

because you want `(sep << args)` to be left-folded with `std::cout`.  This doesn't work, because `sep << args` doesn't know it is being streamed to `std::cout` or streamed at all; `<<` is only streaming if the left hand side is a stream.

In short, the problem is that `sep << args` doesn't understand it is streaming.

Your other problem is not enough lambda.

We can fix this.

```
template<class F>
struct ostreamer_t {
    F f;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, ostreamer_t&& self ) {
        self.f(os);
        return os;
    }
    template<class T>
    friend auto operator<<(ostreamer_t self, T&& t) {
        auto f = [g = std::move(self.f), &t](auto&& os)mutable {
            std::move(g)(os);
            os << t;
        };
        return ostreamer_t<decltype(f)>{std::move(f)};
    }
};

struct do_nothing_t {
    template<class...Args>
    void operator()(Args&&...)const {}
};

const ostreamer_t<do_nothing_t> ostreamer{{}};

template <typename... Args>
void print(Args... args)
{
    std::string sep = " ";
    std::string end = "\n";
    (std::cout << ... << (ostreamer << sep << args)) << end;
}
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a58e01a34e25bf6d). (I also used a literal for `sep` to ensure I work with rvalues).

`ostreamer` captures references to things it is `<<`'d, then dumps them when in turn it is `<<` to an `ostream`.

This entire process should be transparent to the compiler, so a decent optimizer should evaporate everything involved.

Comment: "Your other problem is not enough lambda." What a beautiful solution. :)

Answer (score 3):

As answered by others, you are trying to use a wrong *fold-expression* format.
You could use a lambda helper for your purpose in a very simple way:

```
template <typename... Args>
void print(Args&&... args)
{
    std::string sep = " ";
    std::string end = "\n";
    auto streamSep = [&sep](const auto& arg) -> decltype(arg) {
        std::cout << sep;
        return arg;
    };
    (std::cout << ... << streamSep(args)) << end;
}
```

This will follow the behaviour expected in the code you wrote. However, if you want to avoid the *sep* before the first argument, you could use the following:

```
template <typename Arg, typename... Args>
void print(Arg&& arg, Args&&... args)
{
    std::string sep = " ";
    std::string end = "\n";
    auto streamSep = [&sep](const auto& arg) -> decltype(arg) {
        std::cout << sep;
        return arg;
    };
    std::cout << arg;
    (std::cout << ... << streamSep(args)) << end;
}
```

Comment: I'm not an expert on lambdas but could you, hypothetically, make the lambda into a function and put it right above the print function? Or would that be more complicated and/or generate worse assembly?

Comment: @nickeb96 If we start from the idea we want to optimize this example (just because I have the two _unoptimized_ parameters _sep_ and _end_ and I am not sure how I have to handle them), then we can easily obtain the same assembly (according to GCC 7.1) using a function instead of a lambda. Look [at this example](https://godbolt.org/g/TGoYLT): the two versions can be compiled defining or not USE_LAMBDA, and you can see that the result is the same. However, I am not sure I replied to your doubts, because I used _sep_ and _end_ as literals.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is the next:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class U, class... T>
    void printSpaced(const U& u, const T&... args)
{   
     using std::cout;
     using std::endl;         

     ((cout << u) << ... << (cout << ' ', args)) << endl;   
}
```

This way you won't get leading/trailing space
 Usage:

```
printSpaced(1, 2, "Hello", 4.5f); //Output 1 2 Hello 4.5 and no trailing space
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
template <typename... Args>
void print(Args... args)
{
  bool first = true;
  auto lambda = [&](auto param)
  {
    if( !first) std::cout << ',';
    first= false;
    return param;
  };

  ((std::cout << lambda(args)), ...);
}
```

The lambda ensures separator are only inserted between two items.

On the other hand if you dont wanna use lambdas you can overload the template:

```
template<typename T>
void print(T item)
{
  std::cout << item;
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
void print(T item, Args... args)
{
  print(item);
  std::cout << ',';
  print(args...);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want leading/trailing `sep`:

```
template <typename First, typename... Rest>
void print(First first, Rest... rest)
{
    std::string sep = " ";
    std::string end = "\n";

    std::cout << first;
    ((std::cout << sep << rest), ...);
    std::cout << end;
}
```

You need to make `std::cout << end;` a separate instruction to handle case with one parameter.